# Django URL Parameter Key Used Twice

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a simple Django view that just returns URL parameters, but if I use the same parameter key multiple times, I cannot seem to access it. Consider the following set-up:

urls.py:

```
(r'^header/$',header)
```

View function:

```
def header(request)
    return render_to_response('header.html',locals(),mimetype='text/plain')
```

Template:

```
{{ request.GET }}
{% for key,val in request.GET %}
{{ key }} : {{ val }}
{% endfor %}
```

URL:

- `http://mysite/header/?item=1&item=2`

Response:

```
&lt;QueryDict: {u&#39;item&#39;: [u&#39;1&#39;, u&#39;2&#39;]}&gt;

item : 2
```

Should the 'item' entry have the value of '1,2' or "['1','2']"? Notice what the full GET returns. How do I get both values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the [QueryDict](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) which is used to hold the GET/POST attributes.

Specifically:

> QueryDict  is a dictionary-like class customized to deal with **multiple values for the same key**. This is necessary because some HTML form elements, notably `<select multiple="multiple">`, pass multiple values for the same key.

You probably want to use [QueryDict.lists()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists):

```
q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3')
q.lists()
[(u'a', [u'1', u'2', u'3'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's returning the multiple values in a list. In the back-end, you can just check to see if the variable is a list or not and then treat the cases accordingly. It looks like there's some logic to return the last value assigned to a key if you coerce it to a string like you're doing.

Comment: Is there no mechanism to do this from the template?

Comment: @kzh - You don't want to do that in the template, you want to do that in the view.

Comment: @Dom - I generally wouldn't, but I was curious if Django had a mechanism for this, that's all.

Comment: Does the lists "property" mentioned in Lance McNearney's comment work? Check for value.lists and loop over that if it exists.